# Lemmatiztion with Factorie in SBT

Tags: scala, wordnet, lemmatization

I am writing script in scala to lemmatize some text using wordnetlemmatizer from the [this](https://github.com/factorie/factorie/tree/master/src/main/scala/cc/factorie/app/nlp/lemma) link.

API says lemmatizer object can be created `new wordNetLemmatizer(wordnet dir)`

How can i pass this input stream of word net dir as parameter to above.

[This](http://factorie.cs.umass.edu/scaladocs/index.html#cc.factorie.app.nlp.lemma.WordNetLemmatizer$) is my reference.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your link goes to the object WordNetLemmatizer. As you probably now an object is a singleton and you can not do new on an object.
The documentation for the class is here http://factorie.cs.umass.edu/scaladocs/index.html#cc.factorie.app.nlp.lemma.WordNetLemmatizer

The class WordNetLemmatizer offers a constructor with a File, so you can do

```
new WordNetLemmatizer(new File("/home/xxx/wordnet"))
```